# Wordpress - Display Content on page and its children

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, menu

I am trying to implement a submenu into my page.php. It shall be dynamic so the different pages of my site have different submenus displayed on a certain place.

This is what I got so far:

```
<?php if (is_page(unternehmen || $post->post_parent==unternehmen)): ?> <!-- Unternehmen /postID 553 -->

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Unternehmen Submenu' )); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But with this solution the submenu here called "Unternehmen Submenu" will be displayed on every page that uses the page.php. I need a solution that displays the menu only on the respective page defined in the if-statement and its children. The best solution would be if the code fetches the main menu into this. It's an easy menu with one sublevel.

I searched for this specific problem here but didn't found a solution.

Comment: var $unternehmen = 553,
or did i miss something?

Comment: It is not about the comment on the right. I don't really know how to to implement a menu on a page and its children. Maybe there is something in the wordpress codex I don't know about.